# why does this regex to find a simple string not work?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find some matches of sample strings, but I'm flabbergasted as to why it's not working.

here are some sample strings that should be found (there could be any number of words between "the" and "turtle" or "fox"):

```
The Quick Brown Fox
The Slow Green Turtle
The Blah Blah Fox
The Blah Blah Blah Turtle
```

here is the regex that isn't working:

```
if(preg_match("/the \w* (fox|turtle)/i",$str)){
   echo "Match!<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is because space is not handled by \w, and you expect \w* to match 'Quick Brown'.
So  you may try

```
if(preg_match("/the[\w ]*(fox|turtle)/i",$str))
```

to match any number of words between the two blocks.

Comment: @JenBorn: Choose an answer and mark it please. So next user to search will know there is one which matches. TY

Comment: Sorry!  When I tried to accept it right away it wouldn't let me and I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are two words before fox or turtle, not one.

For an undetermined number of words:

```
if ( preg_match('~\bthe(?> \w+)*? (fox|turtle)\b~i', $str) )
```

Note: the lazy quantifier `*?` is needed if you want to match "The slow turtle" with this string: `The slow turtle and the quick fox` *(instead of all the sentence)*